# How to loop only once the duplicate data by using v-for?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am receiving the data from the cloud. I have looked at many questions in StackOverflow, but all of them were using the data in `data()`. I am a super beginner in using Vue.js, so could not apply it in my code.

I would like to display the duplicate data only once in `v-for`.  In this case, `{{item.matched_product.name}}` displays repeatedly.

```
<template slot-scope="scope">
  <div v-if="scope.row.external_store.service_name == 'sellorder'">
    <div
      v-for="item in scope.row.items"
      :key="item.id"
      class="option-detail"
      ref="option_variant"
    >
      <div v-if="item.matched_product">

        <-- This is the part I want to display only once --> 
        <span style="font-weight:bold">
           <i class="el-icon-caret-right"></i>
          {{item.matched_product.name}}
        </span>

        <span>
          <span
            v-if="item.matched_variant">
            {{item.matched_variant.options.map(obj => obj.value).join(' / ')}} {{item.qty}} / {{item.matched_variant.properties && item.matched_variant.properties.soldout ?
            '(sold out)':''}}
          </span>
          <span v-else>No matching</span>&nbsp;
          <el-button size="mini" round @click="matchProduct(scope.row,item)">Edit matching</el-button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <el-button size="mini" @click="matchProduct(scope.row,item)">Match</el-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

What should I do?

[image: This is the one I am having..]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below like @JoshBonnick mentinoed

```
v-for="(item, index) in scope.row.items"
```

and I put this code as well.

```
{{ ((index == 0) || item.matched_product.name != scope.row.items[index-1].matched_product.name) ? item.matched_product.name : '' }}
```

Now, this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `index` in your `for loop` by doing the following

```js
v-for="(item, index) in scope.row.items"
```

Then you can just add a `v-if` to the element you want to only display once to check `if` `index` is `0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you mentioned, and I added ```v-for="(item, index) in scope.row.items"```, but I have got another issue which it doesn't show another ```matched_product.name``` in the same element..

Comment: You have this now right? `<span style="font-weight:bold" v-if="index == 0">
           <i class="el-icon-caret-right"></i>
          {{item.matched_product.name}}
        </span>`

Comment: Yes, I wrote that way, and I put ```v-for="(item, index) in scope.row.items"``` in line 4, and now, I have only one ```matched_product.name``` which would have different names from time to time. I just added photo! The array ```scope.row.items```would receive many different ```matched_product.name```.

Comment: ```{{ ((index == 0) || item.matched_product.name != scope.row.items[index-1].matched_product.name) ? item.matched_product.name : '' }}``` I did this, and it works!! Thank you for your answer anyways!!